# jQuery slider/carousel with interval countdown animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I'm working on a jquery slider/carousel to rotate between a couple of promotions.

What I'm looking for is a way to show the remaining time until the next promotion slides in. Exactly as the flash promo at: http://www.nordicbet.com

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Didn't find any carousel addons with that but I did find one that does the little circle animation.

http://github.com/tschmidt/timer360

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can add a .gif and synchronize it with your jQuery timer. 
jQuery slider [example](http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/).
Gif [generator](http://www.ajaxload.info/).

Comment: Link to example (coffeescripter.com) seems outdated.